# Best way to show several images periodically

Tags: android, image, animation, drawable

I need to change images in background while without stopping main thread to serve user clicks and so on. So I need to change images each n sec in background image view.
Also I need to change images with animation, for instance simple fade in/out.
I have tried different ways, but haven't received desired result.
To say before, my images are not larger than 50k size.
I have tried to use Animation Drawable, it works good but the problem is that when new activity starts I need to start animation, but program flow freezes on animation drawable or crashes with Out Of Memory Error.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/animation_background"
    >
```

Nevertheless, it crashes on emulator with out of memory, but it seems to work on real device, but I have to wait some time before activity starts. 
I tried to do this from the code, but the same result with it.

```
  this.mBackgroundImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        this.mBackgroundImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        this.mBackgroundImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation_background));
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)this.mBackgroundImage.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();ork on real device.    
I tried to do this from the code, but the same result with it.

  this.mBackgroundImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        this.mBackgroundImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        this.mBackgroundImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation_background));
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)this.mBackgroundImage.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
```

Please give an example to implement this task.

Approximately I need 20 images I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: do you expect to change the image on background_image imageview time to time , please explain

Answer (score 0):

Hye there , i was recently searching for this issue and came across a good solution as it doesn't apply automatic density based scaling of the images and use them as they are.

1- Put all your images in **res/drawable-nodpi** folder, you have to create this folder as it doesn't exist.

2 - Make them automatically change from one to other in an infinite loop.

```
int images[] = { R.drawable.background_1, 
        R.drawable.background_2,
        R.drawable.background_3, 
        R.drawable.background_4,
        R.drawable.background_5, 
        R.drawable.background_6,
        R.drawable.background_7 }; // i've these images in **res/drawable-nodpi**
```

Here is the onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_Animated); 

    handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 5000); // after every 5secs it will change image.

 }
```

Now here comes the part which handles all changing of images , outside onCreate do this.

```
    Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (count >6) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(changeImage);
        } else {

            if (count >= 6)
                count = 0;
            AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f); //here is a bit of animation for ya ;)
            animation1.setDuration(5000);
            animation1.setStartOffset(1300); //time for that color effect
            animation1.setFillAfter(true);
            imageView.startAnimation(animation1);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[count++]);
            handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 5000);
            }
    }
};
```

All done, hope i helped you.